# Post-less combination window & door system

Tags: doors, kitchens, windows, patio

We are planning a remodel and are considering a post-less combination folding window & door system similar to what is shown at:

- http://www.nanawall.com/applications/belvedere-kitchen
- http://user-73717428386.publ.com/LaCantina-Doors-32-page-Catalog#22

I attached a tentative floor plan showing the doors in red and the windows in green and wanted to get a sense if someone has done something like this or if this would be geometrically feasible given the 120 deg corner.

[image: Floorplan]

Comment: Is this a bungalow?   If so, can you pencil in an approximate eaves overhang?

Answer (score 1):

As to whether it is geometrically feasible, I have no idea.  The question you should be asking is whether it is *structurally* feasible. I doubt there is any conceivable way to get a header that turns 120° and would provide enough support in the corner without a post there.  I'm assuming that the dashed line is an existing wall. I would also evaluate whether or not the wall is load bearing - based on the floor plan, it looks like it might need to have a header as well.

I would consult with an engineer or an architect before progressing with floor plans.

Answer (score 0):

Contacting a manufacturer's representative is the only way to really know what it will take to make it happen. Typically they are happy to discuss projects because it allows them to qualify sales leads.